# postgresql and RoR - how quering a json type field where value is in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, postgresql

Say I have a User class with a json type address field that has keys for city and country like this: `adress: {city: 'NY', country: 'USA'}` and I want to get all the users that live in an array of country names like: `country_names = ['Iran', 'Iraq', 'Yemen']`.
How do can I do it in Ruby on Rails?

I've tried:

```
User.where("address->>'country' IN ?", country_names)
```

but I get a syntax error. what is the correct way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of values of the `IN` clause should be enclosed by parentheses:

```
User.where("address->>'country' IN (?)", country_names)
```